# Installing packages from the command line for Jenkins automation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have to do automated testing on a VisualStudio c# Web service Project.
For this I have to download the project using Jenkins, compile it, run it, and then run an automated test on the local webpage, to ensure functionality.
My problem is that when trying to build the project, it won't restore all the NuGet packages needed.
Some of these aren't in packages. config or in project. the project, others are on the web. config but not anywhere else.
I tried nuget.exe and dotNET but these won't download the needed packages
I tried using dotNET to add packages to the project but there's an error:
"El proyecto no permite agregar referencias de paquete mediante el comando add package"
The project doesn't allow package references through the add package command.
I tried adding the references manually through a script that adds the XML nodes and through that I managed to make NuGet restore download the packages but these were not installed properly, I was left with *.nupkg files that I then had to unzip.
And now that I'm at my wits' end in regards to this issue I need help to solve this problem.
I would prefer if I can be as unintrusive on the developers on the project, but I'll do whatever is needed.

Comment: You are using the project based on .NET Core? Have you also selected the `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` and `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio` options in Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General > Package Restore? And tried to right-click the solution node and choose `Restore NuGet Packages` option to restore NuGet packages? Besides, does `Install-Package "package name"` command work?

Comment: @Tianyu It's a ASP .Net Core project, i have tried them, none of them work. Restore NuGet packagesit's the same as the command nuget restore, it doesnt see hat there are packages missing. Install-Package gives me an error: "no match was found for the specified search criteria". The full error in spanish:

Comment: Install-Package : No se encontró ninguna coincidencia para el criterio de búsqueda especificado y el nombre de paquete
'ITextSharp'. Prueba Get-PackageSource para ver todos los orígenes de paquete registrados disponibles.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Install-Package 'ITextSharp'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Comment: Looks like the name of the NuGet package is wrong, I mean `ITextSharp` == > `iTextSharp`. Besides, it seems the version number is needed. I searched it on nuget.org [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/), for this specific package, please try if this works: `Install-Package iTextSharp -Version 5.5.13.2`.

Comment: Yeah i tried multiple variations of the name i always got the same error. This time it returned this:
Install-Package : No se encuentra ningún parámetro que coincida con el nombre del parámetro 'Version'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 28
+ Install-Package iTextSharp -Version 5.5.13.2
+                            ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Comment: I think -Version is for nuget package manager, im using just powershell, i tried looking into how to access the nuget package manager from the console but i couldnt find anything, everything lead me to open it from visualstudio

Comment: Looking around more i think it's posible that the project isnt .Net Core as i thought but .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: If it is a .NET Framework related project and you are using powershell, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-nuget-cli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after lots of trial and error i managed to get the project working by making sure the packages.config, Project.csproj and Project.sln files were exactly the same as a working version of the project. After that i use nuget restore to download the packages and unzip them with a .bat file. It isnt pretty but it's what worked.